# MapView is taking whole space in layout

Tags: android

I'm tired of trying to fix this but no luck.

I have layout composed of Map View, seek bar and EditText.

the problem the mapview is taking whole space, so the EditText text do not appear.

I tried to play with weight value but no luck.

appreciate your help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    a:layout_width="fill_parent"

    a:layout_height="fill_parent" >


        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:apiKey="somekey"
            android:clickable="true" 

             android:layout_weight="0"
            a:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             />

       <SeekBar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            a:paddingLeft="10dip"
            a:paddingRight="10dip"
            a:paddingTop="30dip"
            android:max="100" >
        </SeekBar>

 <EditText
            a:id="@+id/smsBody"
            a:layout_width="0dip"
            a:layout_height="wrap_content"
            a:layout_weight="1.0"
            a:autoText="true"
            a:capitalize="sentences"
            a:hint="@string/sms_enter_message"
            a:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
            a:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            a:maxLines="10"
            a:nextFocusRight="@+id/send_button"
            a:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: just curious - `a:something="something_else"` really works for you? shouldn't it be `android:...`

Comment: you have also pointers to elements that doesn't exist like: `"@+id/send_button"`

Comment: @cyborg86pl: yes, actually, when I try to use android:soemthing="somethingelse" it doesn't work. i dont know why

Comment: You are naming the xml namespace containing the android tags `a` by the statement `xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`. Hence `android:` doesn't work, but `a:` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should regulate the elements with  `android:layout_weight`. For example in this way:
I hope it will work.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="15" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6" >

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/maplayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/smsBody"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:hint="test" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3" >

            <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:apiKey="XXX" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to apply a layout weight directly on the MapView. Instead, put the MapView inside a parent container e.g. a FrameLayout and apply the layout weight e.g. 0.7 to the parent container.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need, try setting this properties in either the MapView or the other elements:

`android:layout_above="@+id/.."` or the `android:layout_below="@+id/..."`.

And delete all the weight attributes, they have no use in a RelativeLayout because you can do your job with the described properties. `layout_weight` is commonly used in `LinearLayout` when all the elements are in a stack and not "stuffed" inside a layout.

These properties are used when the parent layout is a `RelativeLayout`, and determine what layout should be above the other and generally the whole orientation. It has also the `layout_toLeftOf` and `layout_toRightOf` for the left or right orientation respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Just two simple lines of code and your done with it :)

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:layout_above="@+id/headerRow"


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HERE GOES YOUR TEXT" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/headerRow"
        android:apiKey="mykey"
        android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will surely help you to get  your work done perfectly.

Thanks :)